Prevent closing of shadcn Sheet component based on a certain condition
I am trying to prevent closing the Sheet component from shadcn/ui when validations on the data input by the user inside the sheet component fails. Currently, when button is clicked, even if there are validation errors handled by the Form, the Sheet closes and I have to manually reopen the component to fix the issue. The code is as follows
<Sheet>
  <SheetTrigger asChild>...</SheetTrigger>
  <SheetContent>
    <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
      <Form { ...form }>
         <form onSubmit={ form.handleSubmit(onSubmit) } className="w-full space-y-6">
           ...
           <SheetFooter>
             <SheetClose asChild>
               <Button type="submit">Save changes</Button>
             </SheetClose>
           </SheetFooter>
         </form>
       </Form>
    </div>
  </SheetContent>
</Sheet >

I tried adding properties like aria-errormessage, onError and onErrorCapture to the SheetClose element, but that doesn't prevent closing the sheet.
aria-errormessage='Please correct all errors' 
onError={ (event) => event.preventDefault }
onErrorCapture={ (event) => event.preventDefault }


You can acheive this in many ways. One of them is to:

make the <Sheet /> controlled
only update the controller if the condition fulfills

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

return (
  <Sheet
    open={isOpen}
    onOpenChange={(newValue) => {
      if (newValue) setIsOpen(true); // when it's closed, allow opening it

      // when it's opened
      if (form.isValid) setIsOpen(newValue);

      // otherwise, don't do anything
    }}
  >
    ...
  </Sheet>
)


I marked the answer as accepted now

When I use the following code, the sheet stays open if there's an error (which is an expected behavior), but it does not close when I click the Close button. How do I make the sheet close ?
<Sheet open={isOpen} onOpenChange={() => setIsOpen(true)}>    


onOpenChange has to be a more complicated function that has all the logic for opening and closing the sheet. The exact structure of the function will depend on the use case
